How can I make a React and Firebase web app more secure?
I built a web app that has authentication with firebase, but I am looking for ways to make it more secure. Functionality includes reading and writing to firebase if you are an authenticated user. All this data needs to be protected to comply with some laws, which is why I need suggestions. I am thinking of adding SSO among other things. Using react for frontend, node and express for backend/api and firebase for db. Thanks!

If not all authenticated users need the same level of access you can use Firebase Security Rules to define any possible roles (admin, reader, writer, etc) and restrict with those roles as such.
You also mention compliance, which means you might have a reason/need to audit logs  (of who accessed or changed what) at some point. You can use Firebase functions/Firestore triggers to log these and then export to wherever for viewing.
